# Get owned items list in In-app-billing

Tags: cordova

How to parse response value of getOwnItems(successHandler, errorHandler) in in-app-billing.  Now parsed like

```
 if(typeof result === 'object') {
     strResult = JSON.stringify(result);
  } else {
      strResult = result;
  }alert("SUCCESS: \r\n"+strResult );
```

In this I got empty value. If I print without converting to  "JSON.stringify(result);" it prints like "[object Object]". I already buy one item.

Can you explain get the owned items list.

Comment: I am also have the same problem.